# Landing URL after got connected by router (no auth)

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I've been looking for this simple feature since months. All I need to do is to redirect users to my website after they have just connected to my open wifi network. I don't even need any auth service / agree terms.

However, captive portals are focused on auth services. I've been told to use NoCatSplash, but I've already installed DD-WRT v24 sp2 (build 21061, 03/25/13) on my TP-Link WR-740N but **it is missing**.

Why isn't it showing up? Is there any other simple alternative?

Related topics:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=284114 ("Need to create a hotspot w/ splash only, no auth.")

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=268718 ("Default public URL in my wifi local network")

Comment: any guess guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a very nice solution provided by [NoDogSplash](https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash). It's very simple to use and configure by editing its config file. OpenWRT (luci) is a lot easier to install than before and provides a user-friendly web-interface.

This is how NoDogSplash describes itself at GitHub,

> Nodogsplash offers a solution to this problem: You want to provide
>   controlled and reasonably secure public access to an internet
>   connection; and while you want to require users to give some
>   acknowledgment of the service you are providing, you don't need or
>   want the complexity of user account names and passwords and
>   maintaining a separate database-backed authentication server.
>
> When installed and running, Nodogsplash implements a simple
>   'authentication' protocol. First, it detects any user attempting to
>   use your internet connection to request a web page. It captures the
>   request, and instead serves back a 'splash' web page using its own
>   builtin web server. The splash page contains a link which, when the
>   user clicks on it, opens limited access for them to the internet via
>   your connection, beginning by being redirected to their originally
>   requested page, or a specified URL. This access expires after a certain time interval.
>   Nodogsplash also permits limiting the aggregate bandwidth provided to
>   users, if you don't want to grant all of your available upload or
>   download bandwidth. Specific features of Nodogsplash are configurable,
>   by editing the configuration file and the splash page. The default
>   installed configuration may be all you need, though.